# Как работает union?

Tags: c++, c

```
union Foo
{
int a;
float b;
long double c;
char d;
};
```

Как `union` может интерпретировать пам'ять для разных типов?

Comment: "Как uinon может интерпретировать" - как int, float, long double или char - в зависимости от того, к чему вы обратитесь: к a, b, c или d соответственно. Хотя что-то я подозреваю, что вы ожидали получить в ответ не это, но на вопрос в текущем виде ответ именно такой

Comment: `union` может интерпретировать память только для одного типа

Answer (score 1):

Ну, объединения в С и С++ работают очень просто. Ты указываешь, что вот в этой области памяти у тебя будет несколько полей (в примере 4 штуки), но тип каждого из них разный.

Когда ты обращаешься к каждому из этих полей, компилятор создает соответствующие обращения к одной и той же области памяти (по одному адресу), но с разными размерами.

Твой пример немного синтетический, как его использовать в реальности - не могу придумать. Но вот тебе вполне рабочий пример:

```
typedef struct {
    union {
        unsigned int address;
        unsigned char bytes[4];
    }
} ipv4_address;
```

В итоге ты можешь обратиться либо к целому адресу как к 32-битному числу (например чтобы его скопировать), а можешь обратиться к каждому байту из 4 штук, чтобы например вывести адрес в нотации X.X.X.X чем-то вроде `printf("%d.%d.%d.%d",ipv4.bytes[0],ipv4.bytes[1],ipv4.bytes[2],ipv4.bytes[3])`.

То есть Union позволяет смотреть на одну и ту же область памяти через разные "призмы", вернее через разные типы данных.

В принципе ты можешь наложить int и float. Но хорошее из этого вряд ли что получится, поскольку битовое кодирование целых чисел и чисел с плавающей точкой разное, и придумать задачу, где это может пригодиться, у меня не получается )

Кстати, ты можешь не использовать Union вообще, а пойти опасным путем - приводи адрес переменной одного типа к адресу переменной другого типа.

```
unsigned int a = 44;
unsigned char *c = (unsigned char *)(&a);
printf("%d", c[3]); // Выводим последний, то есть 4-ый, октет переменной a
```

Жуть, правда? Никогда так не делай, уж лучше Union. И вообще, это довольно грязные трюки со множеством допущений и подводных камней, в обычной работе лучше сделать то же самое, но надежнее и проще.

Comment: На всякий случай замечу, что данный пример имеет не совсем определённое поведение из-за того, что не на всех платформах длина int и порядок его байтов одинаковые

Comment: Да, я дополнил ответ, чтобы не вводить автора вопроса в заблуждение )

Comment: Для С++ работает как раз второй вариант, а обратиться через union как к 32-битному числу и как к массиву байт не получится.

Comment: На всякий случай замечу, что данный пример имеет совсем неопределённое поведение в С++. Потому что в С++ нельзя использовать неактивноый член объединения. В то время как в С это явно разрешено.

Comment: Во-первых, язык С++ не допускает использование union доя переинтерпретации памяти. Это разрешено только в С. Во-вторых, последний пример с указателями в С и С++ допустим только для переинтерпретации в роли символьного массива, в то время как  union в С позволяет делать любые переинтерпретации. Так что это не одно и то же.